# Formatting Date using handlerbar helpers

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I wrote a helper for handlebars

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('timestamp', function(timeFormat) {
        return moment().format(timeFormat);
});
```

And I'm calling this with

```
{{{timestamp YYYYMMDDHHMMSS}}}
```

But, this doesn't work. `timeFormat` is undefined.

How do I get `timeFormat` in that helper function?

Comment: have you tried adding double quotes to your call in template? like {{{"YYYYMMDDHHMMSS"}}}? no time atm to check it myself, but perhaps this fiddle might help you, too: https://gist.github.com/stephentcannon/3409103

Comment: @Dominik `{{{timestamp "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS"}}}` worked!. Thank you!

Comment: No Problem :) I added an answer, feel free to accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you have to add a string as a param from the template. I assume that using YYYYMMDDHHMMSS without double quotes, you're using an `object` as param, and thus the format-function of momentjs, expecting a string, does not work as expected.

So, you have to call `{{{timestamp "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS"}}}` from your handlebars file.

Btw: Here's a little gist I found, doing some more checks: https://gist.github.com/stephentcannon/3409103 if you want to work with moment() instead of a Date as first param, just remove the first param.